# Why does grep results in different results when used in script or in command line - when trying to find pid?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pid

I'm trying to find the PID of Kibana process running on my Centos7 machine.

I have a script that finds the PID by running the following line:

```
kibana_pid=$(ps -ef | grep elk | grep kibana | awk '{print $2}')
```

(kibana is run from elk folder I created).

In the script, in addition, I check the pid if the user provides the "status" agrument:

```
if [[ $userCommand == "status" && $elk_part == "kibana"  ]]
then
    if [[ -z "$kibana_pid" ]]
    then
            echo "Kibana is not running"
    else
            echo "Kibana is running with pid of: $kibana_pid"
    fi
fi
```

When I run the script with these arguments, the ouput of ./elk_ctl.sh status kibana was:

```
Kibana is running with pid of: 28250
32213
32219
```

But when I run the same command to find the PID outside of the script, in my command line, I get the corrent result - only one PID number:

```
$ps -ef | grep elk | grep kibana | awk '{print $2}'
```

output:

```
28250
```

The weird thing is when I run:

```
$ ps -ef | grep elk | grep kibana
```

I get only one line.

EDIT 1: more weird behavior found:
I added the following line to the begining of the script, so I can see what the pid is when its created:

```
kibana_pid=$(ps -ef | grep elk | grep kibana | awk '{print $2}')
echo "kibana PID at start is: $kibana_pid"
```

When I run:
./elk_ctl status kibana

I get this output:

```
kibana PID at start is: 1634
1640
28250
Kibana is running with pid of: 1634
1640
28250
```

When I run this, however:

./elk_ctl status

(which results in an wring usage message)

I get:

```
kibana PID at start is: 28250
Wrong use. Please run: ./script start/stop/status elasticsearch/kibana
```

What is so special about the "status kibana" combo that results in more than one PID found?

EDIT 2: more weird behavior found:
I changed the echo line at the start of the script to show:

```
echo `ps -ef | grep elk | grep kibana`
```

And the output is:
for ./elk_ctl status kibana -

```
Name 2229 25111 0 12:54 pts/4 00:00:00 /bin/bash ./elk_ctl.sh status kibana 
Name 2240 2229 0 12:54 pts/4 00:00:00 /bin/bash ./elk_ctl status kibana 
Name 28250 1 0 11:05 pts/3 00:00:20 /home/Name/elk/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node --no-warnings /home/Name/elk/kibana/bin/../src/cli
Kibana is running with pid of: 2229
2235
28250
```

for ./elk_ctl.sh status -

```
Name 28250 1 0 11:05 pts/3 00:00:20 /home/Name/elk/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node --no-warnings /home/Name/elk/kibana/bin/../src/cli
Wrong use. Please run: ./script start/stop/status elasticsearch/kibana
```

So again, why there are different results when I use "status kibana" and just "status"?

So my question are:

1. Why the script finds more than one Pid? it's seems that there is only one match in ps.
2. Why the script and the command line have different results? I checked previous answers and most of them has issues with variables or regex in grep, but I have non of them. Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: That shouldn't change anything to your problem but I'd recommend using `pgrep -f 'elk.*kibana'` (or `kibana.*elk` depending on the order of apparition in the command line) rather than parsing the output of `ps`

Comment: Also you might want to post the command-lines of the process that were incorrectly matched by your script, this might provide some insight into what your problem is

Comment: @Aaron: thanks for the suggestion, I did that and found out some more weird stuff. I added it to the post.

Comment: I guess the two additional processes found are the script `./script … elk … kibana …` and the grep commands `grep elk …`.

Comment: You did *not* post what Aaron wanted. We want to see the output of `ps -ef | grep elk | grep kibana` (note the missing `awk` part) for cases where more than one line matches.

Comment: Seing your edit : probably what @Socowi said ; once you add kibana to your script's command line, it gets matched by your ps+grep+awk (meaning it must have an 'elk' somewhere else in the output of `ps`, maybe the user or group name?

Comment: @Socowi:
Thanks for the input, I'm adding what you asked to the post

Comment: That's definitely weird. If "Name" is a placeholder, does the actual value contain 'elk' ? Otherwise you might get better insight running the script with `bash -x`

Comment: @Aaron:
Name is a placeholder, and it does not contain "elk".

Comment: Ah, I don't know what I was looking at, but the grep is matching `elk` in `elk_ctl.sh` and `kibana` from your script's parameters. A solution would be to exclude your script from matches by using `grep -v ./elk_ctl.sh`

Comment: @Aaron: this might be it.

Comment: `grep elk | grep kibana | awk '{print $2}'` = `awk '/elk/ && /kibana/{print $2}'`. Also the common way to find a process containing `foo` is with `pgrep` or `ps options | grep '[f]oo'` - the `[f]` so that `[f]oo` won't match `foo` in the `ps` output.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue with the help of @Aaron - thanks!
The script name is elk_ctl.sh, so the grep matched it.
When I changed the script name to a name not containing "elk" in it, the issue was gone.
So even though I could not find an explanation for why runnig "status kibana" was different than just "status", I solved the issue, so I counsider this as an answer.
Thank you for all who commented.

Comment: The explication is the following : `ps -ef | grep elk | grep kibana` will only output lines of `ps -ef` that contain both elk and kibana. Your script's command line always contained elk since it was in its name, but it only contained kibana (and was then displayed) when you passed it as parameter